# How to get my original ROM working again?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, rom

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830L and I a few days ago downloaded and installed a custom ROM 4.2.2 the name of the file is (cm-10.1-20130503-NIGHTLY-cooper), It worked good at first, but then the apps didn't download it used a lot of memory, it crashed/hanged and it became annoying, So I'm trying to return to my previous original version 2.3.4, but It doesn't work... I made a backup with clockworks, but it doesn't work. I tried downloading one from the internet and using thor (i think that was its name) to install it, but it doesn't connect succeed anytime I try... I also tried with kies, but It didn't work, it just staid there for hours without doing anything...

So what are my options to restore the original ROM?, I really need to get back to it, this version is just to buggy and annoying for me to stay with it.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't give us enough information to help you. If you say exactly what you did, and what happened, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Also, you might like to try the *stable* Cyanogenmod ROM instead of the *nightly build*. The nightly build may or may not work on any given day, but the stable build is tested and should be reliable.

Comment: I agree with @DanHulme, using nightly builds as your everyday rom is not a good idea. You need to do some searching to find a mod that fits perfectly to your device. Remember that if you try to load a mod on your phone that is the build for a phone on a different carrier, you could soft brick your device. Close only counts in horseshoes and handgrenades =)

Comment: Sorry about not providing enough information, at the moment I'm going to try to install the latest stable build, Thanks for the help :)